# How can I simuate user account decay in Locust?

Tags: locust

Firt, I specify user account 1500, spawrate 1, which would take 25 minutes, then I'd like to decrease 1 per second within 900 seconds. how can I simulate this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to use the Load Shape feature of Locust. It lets you define in code what you want the user count and spawn rate to be at any given time.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/generating-custom-load-shape.html